# how to exchange data in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have the **table structure** below

[image]

how so that, if processed with the button, `id_modul` can change

```
id id_level id_modul
1    1        1
2    1        3
3    1        2
```

please, help me!

Comment: Can you explain that in detail, please?

Comment: so, if I want to change the module id from id_module 1 to move to id_module 3 and vice versa id_module 3 to id_module 1 based on idny

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$module = Module::where('id_level', 1)->where('id_module', 3)->get();

$module->update(['id_module' => 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$foo_2 = Foo::where('id_modul', 2)->get();
$foo_3 = Foo::where('id_modul', 3)->get();
foreach ($foo_2 as $foo) {
    $foo->id_modul = 3;
    $foo->save();
}
foreach ($foo_3 as $foo) {
    $foo->id_modul = 2;
    $foo->save();
}
```